# Json server running but not fetching data for react native app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, json-server, server-error

I am new to the backend and don't fully understand all this:

Started the server with `json-server -H 0.0.0.0 --watch db1.json -p 3001 -d 2000` and it starts correctly.
[My terminal window when I start the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq4YY.png). The weird thing is that if I follow the links, the resources show up in the browser correctly and a GET request goes through successfully.

I next start expo and that also starts correctly. When I go to view it in the expo app on my phone, it doesn't load the resources on the server and gives me the error message of "Network request failed".
I haven't touched this project in a month and have actually been working on other backend related stuff, so maybe I installed something that messes with the server.

Comment: use `http://10.0.2.2:3001/` this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that ip address of your fetch statement in the React Native app is the same as that of your server. For example if your ip address is  127.0.0.1:3001  then your fetch statement should be: fetch('127.0.0.1:3001')

you can findout your ip address with ipconfig -a

Comment: ipconfig -all is the correct command for windows

Comment: Whatdo you mean fetch statement? I added ```--host <ip address>``` to my command to start the json server and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed wifi networks and didn't realize my ip address would be different. I had to change the code accordingly.